# Rule/Replace/Patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, trigonometry, rule

I need help with doing this question.

given: Sin[x+y] 
       Cos[x+y+z]

Define using Patterns a rule (specifically a list of 2 rules ) , the two adding rules for trigonometric functions sin (a + b ) = sin ( a) cos ( b ) + cos ( a) sin ( b ) and cos (a + b) = cos (a) cos ( b) - sin (A) sin(b) applies .

thanks for your help!

---

thanks for the fast answer. I've send the wrong exercise.
they are two different excersices.

1) Sin(p+q)

2) Cos(x+y+z)

not both together sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to answer a homework assignment.